# Create function in vertica

Tags: vertica, vsql

I checked through many sources but cudnt get result.

> How to create a function in vertica to return count of all sessions in
>   database?

Can someone povide some idea or possible expamples in this topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> create C++(count_it.cpp )

```
#include "Vertica.h"
#include <time.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace Vertica;
using namespace std;

class Average : public AggregateFunction
{
    virtual void initAggregate(ServerInterface &srvInterface, IntermediateAggs &aggs)
    {
        try {
            VNumeric &sum = aggs.getNumericRef(0);
            sum.setZero();

            vint &cnt = aggs.getIntRef(1);
            cnt = 0;
        } catch(exception& e) {
             vt_report_error(0, "Exception while initializing intermediate aggregates: [%s]", e.what());
        }
    }

    void aggregate(ServerInterface &srvInterface, BlockReader &argReader, IntermediateAggs &aggs)
    {
        try {
            VNumeric &sum = aggs.getNumericRef(0);
            vint     &cnt = aggs.getIntRef(1);

            do {
                const VNumeric &input = argReader.getNumericRef(0);
                if (!input.isNull()) {
                    sum.accumulate(&input);
                    sum.setZero();
                    cnt++;
                }
            } while (argReader.next());
        } catch(exception& e) {
            vt_report_error(0, "Exception while processing aggregate: [%s]", e.what());
        }
    }

    virtual void combine(ServerInterface &srvInterface,IntermediateAggs &aggs,MultipleIntermediateAggs &aggsOther)
    {
        try {
            VNumeric       &mySum      = aggs.getNumericRef(0);
            vint           &myCount    = aggs.getIntRef(1);

            do {
                const VNumeric &otherSum   = aggsOther.getNumericRef(0);
                const vint     &otherCount = aggsOther.getIntRef(1);

                mySum.accumulate(&otherSum);
                mySum.setZero();
                myCount += otherCount;

            } while (aggsOther.next());
        } catch(exception& e) {
            vt_report_error(0, "Exception while combining intermediate aggregates: [%s]", e.what());
        }
    }

    virtual void terminate(ServerInterface &srvInterface, BlockWriter &resWriter, IntermediateAggs &aggs)
    {
        try {
            const VerticaType  &numtype = aggs.getTypeMetaData().getColumnType(0);
            const VNumeric     &sum     = aggs.getNumericRef(0);
            sum.setZero();

            uint64* tmp = (uint64*)malloc(numtype.getMaxSize() / sizeof(uint64));
            VNumeric cnt(tmp, numtype.getNumericPrecision(), numtype.getNumericScale());
            cnt.copy(aggs.getIntRef(1));
            VNumeric &out = resWriter.getNumericRef();
            if (cnt.isZero())
                out.setZero();
            else
                out.add(&cnt,&sum);
        } catch(exception& e) {
            vt_report_error(0, "Exception while computing aggregate output: [%s]", e.what());
        }
    }

    InlineAggregate()
};


class count_itFactory : public AggregateFunctionFactory
{
    virtual void getPrototype(ServerInterface &srvfloaterface,ColumnTypes &argTypes,ColumnTypes &returnType)
    {
        argTypes.addNumeric();
        returnType.addNumeric();
    }

    virtual void getReturnType(ServerInterface &srvfloaterface,const SizedColumnTypes &inputTypes,SizedColumnTypes &outputTypes)
    {
        int int_part = inputTypes.getColumnType(0).getNumericPrecision();
        int frac_part = inputTypes.getColumnType(0).getNumericScale();
        outputTypes.addNumeric(int_part+frac_part, frac_part);
    }

    virtual void getIntermediateTypes(ServerInterface &srvInterface,const SizedColumnTypes &inputTypes,SizedColumnTypes &intermediateTypeMetaData)
    {
        int int_part = inputTypes.getColumnType(0).getNumericIntegral();
        int frac_part = inputTypes.getColumnType(0).getNumericFractional();
        intermediateTypeMetaData.addNumeric(int_part+frac_part, frac_part);
        intermediateTypeMetaData.addInt();
    }

    virtual AggregateFunction *createAggregateFunction(ServerInterface &srvfloaterface)
    { return vt_createFuncObject<Average>(srvfloaterface.allocator); }

};

RegisterFactory(count_itFactory);
```

> compile C++

```
g++ -D HAVE_LONG_INT_64 -I /opt/vertica/sdk/include -Wall -shared -Wno-unused-value -fPIC -o count_it.so /home/dbadmin/libs/count_it.cpp /opt/vertica/sdk/include/Vertica.cpp
```

> create library

```
CREATE LIBRARY count_it AS '/home/dbadmin/libs/count_it.so';
```

> create function

```
CREATE AGGREGATE FUNCTION count_it AS LANGUAGE 'C++' NAME 'count_itFactory' LIBRARY count_it;
```

> use function

```
  select count_it(client_id) from sesions;
```

Comment: There are multiple errors in this answer: (1) sessions and not sesions, (2) memory is allocated but not freed, (3) malloc is casted, (4) you do not control if malloc really allocates memory, (5) aggregate functions need Group by, etc... This is a perfect example of how NOT to write code.

Answer (score 0):

You can create UDX in Vertica, but it does not have a session handle so you can only access data exposed via the API. Session data is not exposed.

You'll need to execute a query to do it.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sessions;
```

Comment: I know about this query. Its just that i want to try functions which returns table data.

Comment: Can't be done, sorry. There are no stored procedures in Vertica, UDX does not have a session handle for query purposes. Query is your only choice.

Answer (score 0):

See this post for something similar:

```
SELECT
 node_name
,user_name
,'SELECT CLOSE_SESSION(''' || session_id || ''');'  AS CloseSession
,statement_start
,(GETDATE() - statement_start)::INTERVAL  AS current_statement_duration
,REGEXP_REPLACE(current_statement,'[rnt]',' ') AS current_statement
,session_id
,transaction_id
,statement_id
,client_hostname
,client_os
,login_timestamp
,runtime_priority
,ssl_state
,authentication_method
,transaction_start
,GETDATE() AS Today
```

FROM v_monitor.sessions
ORDER BY current_statement_duration DESC
;

Also you can get more info from this post:
**[Script to List Vertica Active Sessions](http://www.aodba.com/script-list-vertica-active-sessions/)**